# Identifying and accessing files on a TK800 Smart display car key

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit

I've bought this Chinese TK800 smart car key from Aliexpress and it seems that they have locked it and I can't access the files from a PC via USB.
I'm trying to add or change a car model image from within the key to add my own, so I tried opening up the key to find out what chip it's using since I was thinking it is a generic MTK device but I can't find any details on the chips it has.

[image: TK800 Smart Key]

Does anyone have any idea on what its brains are or how to access its system files?

Comment: What makes you think it has any "system files", or files of any sort at all? I think it's much more likely to just have relevant data programmed into its internal flash, with no filesystem of any kind involved.

Comment: Well previous software versions allowed the device to be turned off and when connected to a PC it would act as a USB flash drive. Also the fact that it has an UI with settings makes me think it has an actual OS called MAUI (MRE) and from what other people dug up it should be running a MTK2502DV CPU (which I can’t find on the board)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this as I have also purchased the same key.

Comment: Sadly no, we need an engineer or hacker who's able to read and edit the contents of the chip, I wasn't even able to figure out which chip has all the data